# Using an ID against dates for picking - problem when lastWeekEnd and lastMonthEnd are the same date

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that appeared to work well at first but needs a slight tweak. Where I am right in the middle of it I've got a total mind block on the tweak so I'm throwing it out there for assistance! :)

As part of a larger stored proc, this section goes away to a`MarketDataHistory` table to get columns for `lastBusnessDay`, `lastWeekEnd` (|friday / business day) and `lastMonthEnd`.

I've used a `CASE` to appoint an integer (`1` for `lastBusinessDay`, `2` for `lastWeek` and `3` for `lastMonthEnd` and then `4` for anything else such that we can select only  `IN (1,2,3)` on the outer `SELECT`.

This seemed cool except I then noticed in testing last week that lastWeek and lastMonthEnd were both 31 May and then I had missing values further down the line (we always need columns for all 3 later).

```html
DECLARE @date DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT @lastBusinessDay = (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,
                    (CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, convert(date,@date))
      WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                        WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 
                        ELSE -1
                      END),
                      CONVERT(DATE, @date))) + ' 00:00:00.000')


DECLARE @mydate datetime
SELECT @lastWeek = DATEADD(day, (DATEDIFF (day, '19990102', @DATE) / 7) * 7, '19990101') as friday_before_mydate

SELECT @lastMonthEnd = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1);
Ranked AS
(SELECT ISIN
--,[DATE] 
,GRP
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date, grp ORDER BY t.isin) AS [ROWNUMBER]
,COALESCE(ISNULL(TRY_CAST(BID_SPREAD AS FLOAT) + TRY_CAST(ASK_SPREAD AS FLOAT),0) / 2, 0) AS CLOSE_BIDASKAVG
,COALESCE(ISNULL(TRY_CAST(ASK AS FLOAT) + TRY_CAST(BID AS FLOAT),0) / 2, 0) AS CLOSE_PRICEAVG
,COALESCE(ISNULL(TRY_CAST(ASK_YIELD AS FLOAT) + TRY_CAST(BID_YIELD AS FLOAT),0) / 2, 0) AS CLOSE_YIELDAVG

FROM (SELECT *, (CASE WHEN date = @lastBusinessDay THEN 1 
      WHEN date = @lastWeek THEN 2
      WHEN date = @lastMonthEnd THEN 3 
      ELSE 4 
    END) as GRP --1 for yesterday, 2 for last week, 3 for last month end and ignore 4 on outer
FROM marketdatahistory
WHERE DATE >= @lastMonthEnd
) t
WHERE GRP IN (1,2,3)
AND isin <> '')
```

I'd appreciate someone helping me past my mind block, haha, with a tweak on how I cope with 2 of 3 variables sometimes being the same but always retrieving all 3.

Thanks

Leigh Tilley (TilleyTech Ltd)

Comment: I am sure this makes sense in context of whatever you trying to do but I can't even begin to wrap my head around what you are trying to accomplish here. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your feedback. Based on this I just realised I'd overloaded/overshared thus I've removed the subsequent queries to focus on the bit I have a mental block on. In this first query I assign the GROUP to the data I find per dates given (lastBusinessDay, lastWeek, lastMonthEnd) and 4 for anything else. In testing last week I realised that if lastWeek and lastMonthEnd are the same date we'll miss a group (also would apply to lastBusinessDay and lastMonthend too).

Comment: Can we get some sample input values for `marketdatahistory`, formatted as a `CREATE TABLE` plus `INSERT` statements? And some sample output values, showing which rows you're not getting now?

Comment: Is the problem that when `lastMonthEnd` = `lastWeek`, you want your rows to appear twice?

Comment: Hey yes. i realised that eitehr lastMonthEnd = lastWeek or lastMonthEnd = lastBusinessDay. We always want to get data values back for all three concepts regardless of if 2/3 happen to be the same. I can get some data too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the desired result is that when two conditions are both true you want the rows to appear twice, then you want a join, not a `case`. Focusing in on your inner `SELECT`:

```
FROM (SELECT M.*, G.GRP
FROM marketdatahistory AS M
INNER JOIN (
--1 for yesterday, 2 for last week, 3 for last month end
    SELECT 1 AS GRP, @lastbusinessday as D UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS GRP, @lastWeek as D UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS GRP, @lastMonthEnd as D
) AS G
ON M.DATE >= @lastMonthEnd
AND M.DATE = G.D
) t
```

Since you're going to exclude your group 4s anyway, just don't define those rows at all; that's why I left it out of my innermost select.

Comment: *Note: I have changed it from a FULL JOIN to an INNER JOIN*

Comment: Hey that's great mate; thanks for super fast responses. I'll try it out now.

Comment: I had to change WHERE to ON for it to compile/let me run it but it seems to be what I want. Thanks for the knock on the head / clarity. :)

Comment: for posterity I've changed the answer from `WHERE` to `ON` .. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: If you think it sufficiently answers your question, please *accept* the answer (click the checkmark button)

Comment: Hey no need to apologise; thanks for your swift assistance! :). Ah yes I need to accept it.